# TextBox doesnt have IsReadOnlyCaretVisible Property

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-8

I am creating a Windows Phone 8.0 (Silverlight) app and I am trying to show the caret I a readonly TextBox, but it doesn't have such property.

[documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.isreadonlycaretvisible%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: The documentation that you are referring to is for WPF. Silverlight and Silverlight for Windows Phone are different frameworks. There simply is no such property in Silverlight for WP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you develop Windows Phone 8.0 (Silverlight) you should use following doc site:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/ff402535.aspx

In the Silverlight you have only available `TextBox.IsReadOnly` property [TextBox doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.windows.controls.textbox_properties(v=vs.105).aspx) - [TextBox IsReadOnly doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.windows.controls.textbox.isreadonly(v=vs.105).aspx)

TextBox IsReadOnly remarks:

> If the text box is read-only, no user input or edits are allowed, but
>   programmatic changes can be made. The user can still select text, and
>   the cursor still appears. The KeyUp and KeyDown events are marked as
>   handled.